# why password is validated twice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm configuring ASP.NET Core Identity's password validations with custom validations, so in the `startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...
   services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>( opts => {
       opts.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
   }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddTransient<IPasswordValidator<AppUser>, CustomPasswordValidator>();
   ...
}
```

and my customer password validator is

```
public class CustomPasswordValidator : PasswordValidator<AppUser>
{
    public override async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(UserManager<AppUser> manager, AppUser user, string password)
    {
        IdentityResult result = await base.ValidateAsync(manager, user, password);
        List<IdentityError> errors = result.Succeeded ? new List<IdentityError>() : result.Errors.ToList();
        if (password.ToLower().Contains(user.UserName.ToLower()))
        {
            errors.Add(new IdentityError
            {
                Code = "PasswordContainsUserName",
                Description = "Password cannot contain username"
            });
        }
       
        return errors.Count == 0 ? IdentityResult.Success : IdentityResult.Failed(errors.ToArray());
    }

}
```

and when I ran the app and typed an invalid password whose length < 6,  there is a duplicated validation output as:

> Passwords must be at least 6 characters.
>
> Passwords must be at least 6 characters.

I guess it is because I called the `base`'s `ValidateAsync()`(which contains the validation login in the `startup.cs`), but isn't that my `CustomPasswordValidator` override `base`'s `ValidateAsync()`, so the base's validation should only be called once?

Comment: Try putting a break point in the validation method and see where it is getting called.

Comment: no much help in putting a break point in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> services.AddTransient<IPasswordValidator<AppUser>, CustomPasswordValidator>();
> ```

This call doesn't *replace* the `IPasswordValidator<AppUser>` registration already added by the call to `AddIdentity`; it *adds another*. This means you end up with *two* password-validators, both of which check the same set of built-in rules.

Usually, when requesting a type from DI, we ask for a single implementation. Here's an example constructor:

```
public SomeClass(ISomeService someService) { }
```

If *two* implementations have been registered for `ISomeService`, this constructor is given an instance of the one that is registered *last*. However, we can still get *both* instances by updating the constructor to request a *collection* of `ISomeService`. Here's an example of that:

```
public SomeClass(IEnumerable<ISomeService> someServices) { }
```

In this scenario, with two registered implementations of `ISomeService`, `someServices` contains instances of *both* implementations. This is exactly [what happens in `UserManager`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L70), which was designed to support multiple validators.

Viewing the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L2506) for `UserManager.ValidatePasswordAsync` shows how the validators are enumerated and executed in sequence:

> ```
> foreach (var v in PasswordValidators)
> {
>     var result = await v.ValidateAsync(this, user, password);
>     if (!result.Succeeded)
>     {
>         errors.AddRange(result.Errors);
>     }
> }
> ```

This means that, instead of extending `PasswordValidator<AppUser>`, `CustomPasswordValidator` can just implement `IPasswordValidator<AppUser>` directly:

```
public class CustomPasswordValidator : IPasswordValidator<AppUser>
{
    public async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(UserManager<AppUser> manager, AppUser user, string password)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The code inside your implementation method stays the same, except for it calling into `base`.

Answer (score 0):

I find that you need to register your `CustomPasswordValidator` before the `service.AddIdentity`

```
services.AddTransient<IPasswordValidator<AppUser>, CustomPasswordValidator>();

services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>( opts => {
   opts.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```